# How to get height of embedded dynamic UITableView within a static UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to create a screen for entering patient information very similar to the contacts edit screen in iOS.

I think the screen should be a static table with cells for simple things like firstname, lastname, etc.

Within the static table would be cells containing embedded tables with dynamic cells. There would be an embedded table for phone numbers, another for street addresses, and another for medical providers, ... Each of these embedded tables could have zero or more entries.

[image: Top part of contacts screen]
[image: address section of contacts screen]

Is embedding dynamic tables in a static table the right way to do this?

I don't know how to get the height of the embedded content so that I can set the height of the static cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an advanced topic that I cannot cover in depth now, but I will try to give you a few pointers on how to proceed.

1. I would advise against embedding tableviews into other tableviews.
2. Use a dynamic tableview.
3. Create a view model that provides an array of objects for the controller to render.
4. The controller only takes objects from the view model and decides which cells to render (no logic in the controller)
5. In the view model deal with all the complexities of the data (static content, dynamic sub-arrays, sections, if-else statements, ...)
6. Build the complex cells (address cell in your example) using for example stack views.
7. Dealing with multiple fields inside one cell can be tricky, you will have to do some more research on that topic.

There are many tutorials on view model architecture ("mvvm"), google it.

I hope that helps, good luck and happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks. I had initially considered using a single dynamic table and manage it with an array of fields. I thought it might be easier to go with embedded tables but after spending a few days trying to make it work and failing to get the sizing to work, I think I'll go back to doing it the way you suggested.